# text into a text box from a query

Tags: php

I'm trying to present the result of a query into a text box. The $r->context_type returns the correct value, but it is not displayed in the text box. Here's the code snippet for the text box, where have I gone wrong?

```
echo "<input type='text' name='name1' id='' placeholder='$r->context_type' autocomplete='off' tabindex='4' class='txtinput' /> <br />";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plcaeholder just a comment for TextBox.
if you want to set value use it:

```
value='$r->context_type'
```

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to concatenate, try this.

```
echo "<input type='text' name='name1' id='' placeholder='" . $r->context_type . "' autocomplete='off' tabindex='4' class='txtinput' /> <br />";
```

Also, are you sure you want the placeholder to get the variable and not `value=`

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to display it as a placeholder then try

```
echo "<input type='text' name='name1' id='' placeholder='".$r->context_type."' autocomplete='off' tabindex='4' class='txtinput' /> <br />";
```

Or if you want to display and edit it in `input` `text` then do this

```
echo "<input type='text' name='name1' id='' value='".$r->context_type."' autocomplete='off' tabindex='4' class='txtinput' /> <br />";
```

Note: to be able to edit use `value` insted of `placeholder`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the query thru `htmlspecialchars()` to avoid problems with its value being incorrectly interpreted by browser:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='name1' placeholder='" . htmlspecialchars($r->context_type) . "' autocomplete='off' tabindex='4' class='txtinput' /> <br />";
```

however for better readability I'd rather write either

```
$val = htmlspecialchars($r->context_type);
echo "<input type='text' name='name1' placeholder='{$val}' autocomplete='off' tabindex='4' class='txtinput' /> <br />";
```

or

```
printf("<input type='text' name='name1' placeholder='%s' autocomplete='off' tabindex='4' class='txtinput' /> <br />",
```

htmlspecialchars($r->context_type));

Also remove `id=''` as it makes no much sense.